# Error code E0065 & E0169 where there shouldnt be

Tags: c++

I am going along making my csgo cheat via C++. Everything is going well, until I get to the menu, which throws what appears to be false error messages.

Ive tried doing what visual studios "quick fixes" are. It puts a Semi-colon at the end of "ImGuiWindowFlags_NoTitleBar" and changes the first error to a E0169 as well.

```cpp
void Menu::Render()
{
    ImGui::GetIO().MouseDrawCursor = _visible;

    if (!_visible)
        return;

    const auto sidebar_size = get_sidebar_size();
    static int active_sidebar_tab = 0;

    //ImGui::PushStyle(_style);

    ImGui::SetNextWindowPos(ImVec2{ 0, 0 }, ImGuiSetCond_Once);
    ImGui::SetNextWindowSize(ImVec2{ 1000, 400 }, ImGuiSetCond_Once);
    // https://github.com/spirthack/CSGOSimple/issues/63
    // quick fix

    if (ImGui::Begin("testbuild"))
        & _visible,
        ImGuiWindowFlags_NoCollapse | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoTitleBar)) { <line 376

        //auto& style = ImGui::GetStyle();
        ImGui::PushStyleVar(ImGuiStyleVar_ItemSpacing, ImVec2(0, 0));
        {
            ImGui::BeginGroupBox("##sidebar", sidebar_size);
            {
                //ImGui::GetCurrentWindow()->Flags &= ~ImGuiWindowFlags_ShowBorders;

                render_tabs(sidebar_tabs, active_sidebar_tab, get_sidebar_item_width(), get_sidebar_item_height(), false);
            }
            ImGui::EndGroupBox();
        }
        ImGui::PopStyleVar();
        ImGui::SameLine();

        // Make the body the same vertical size as the sidebar
        // except for the width, which we will set to auto
        auto size = ImVec2{ 0.0f, sidebar_size.y };

        ImGui::BeginGroupBox("##body", size);
        if (active_sidebar_tab == TAB_ESP) {
            RenderEspTab();
        }
        else if (active_sidebar_tab == TAB_AIMBOT) {
            RenderEmptyTab();
        }
        else if (active_sidebar_tab == TAB_MISC) {
            RenderMiscTab();
        }
        else if (active_sidebar_tab == TAB_CONFIG) {
            RenderConfigTab();
        }
        ImGui::EndGroupBox();

        ImGui::TextColored(ImVec4{ 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, "FPS: %03d", get_fps());
        ImGui::SameLine(ImGui::GetWindowWidth() - 150 - ImGui::GetStyle().WindowPadding.x);
        if (ImGui::Button("Unload", ImVec2{ 150, 25 })) {
            g_Unload = true;
        }
        ImGui::End();
    }
} <line 418
```

I expected everything to go away, but it didnt. Error messages:

Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  CSGOSimple 376

Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  CSGOSimple 418

Comment: `if (ImGui::Begin("testbuild"))` << extra bracket from the looks of it, but the rest of the if condition looks weird. `& _visible,` could be the wrong  `&` and that comma will probably give you grief.

Comment: `( () ) )) {` doesn't look right.

Comment: Don't use quick fix suggestions as a coding guide.  Use common sense.

Comment: melpomeme, i fixed that it works THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: I spent 20 seconds doing a web search for the function prototype of `ImGui::Begin`.  The first comment on this question is correct.  You have too many brackets.  The correct expression is `if (ImGui::Begin("testbuild", &_visible, ImGuiWindowFlags_NoCollapse | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoTitleBar))`

Comment: First comment is only partly correct. I figured it was only one extra bracket. That explains all of the insanity with the comma operator that followed: the whole thing was a function call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line right here:

```
if (ImGui::Begin("testbuild"))
```

The last parenthesis at the end closes the if statement. That means it expects the next thing to be some statement. An example of something it would expect:

```
if(ImGui::Begin("testbuild")) 
    return; // Notice we need a semicolon here because return is a statement
```

This is because [if statements in C++ can have a statement or a block following it](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html). Since you don't have a semicolon here (because you clearly don't mean for the if statement to end that early) it throws an error.

To fix this, you will need to remove that parenthesis and fix your if statement. It's not completely apparent to me what you actually intend to do here, so you will have to figure that out yourself. But at least you now have an idea of what's happening here.